# Who are the Pandavas?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas

This question was asked by many political speakers in TN, just writing it here, if one could answer.

None of Kunti's sons are born for Pandu. Karna was born to Sun, Yudishtra was born to Dharm, and so on. If none of them are born to Pandu, how come they are Pandavas and how do they even get the right to rule?

This question is not a duplicate of "Why are they called Pandavas and Kauravas?"

They could be called Pandavas when they are born to Pandu. But in reality, the body was born and they don't have any birthright. So again, how come no one who is born to Pandu becomes a Pandava?

Comment: If you think they don't have right to call themselves Pandavas then why are you bothering asking the question. If you are open to understanding then look up the answers provided in the existing question in site. If you want clarification then post a comment underneath the answers there. Or if you already know the answer as it seems from this question then post your view as an answer (hopefully backed by evidence )

Comment: Why u deleted ur old Q and asked the same Q again?

Comment: @Carmensandiego, I am not sure what are you trying to say here. This is a forum and I raised a question for clarification. My disappointment is, if you cannot clarify, just mind your business rather closing the question.  May be some one who knows Mahabharatha well would answer. "That is why the sons of Dhritarashtra are Kauravas and the sons of Pandu are Pandavas." This is what I see and again, Arjuna, Dharma, Bheema are not sons of Pandu.

Comment: @YDS, because some genius closed the question just like this. this one is closed as well and I am already getting a feel like I am wasting time here. Good luck for your Hinduism  Stack Exchange !!!

Comment: If ur Q got closed then u should edit the Q showing how the linked Q is different from ur Q..and if it's really different, it can be reopened.. deleting closed Q and asking same again is not a good idea..

Comment: Karna is not a pandava nor is he kaunteya but he is radheya